# Clipboard manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard

I'm looking for a good program for managing clipboard history on the Ubuntu desktop used primaraly for software development. Ditto is exactly what I need, except it wont run on Ubuntu.

Comment: See my answer about [A simple clipboard manager for Gnome](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19934/a-simple-clipboard-manager-for-gnome) on Software Recommendations.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**[Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper)** is a GNOME clipboard app, and **[Parcelite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/)** is a GTK+ clipboard manager. Both should be available to install from the repository.

If you're using Unity or GNOME Shell, **[ClipIt](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt)** is a fork of Parcellite with AppIndicator support (thanks @pydave). It has a [Ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clipit).

Comment: parcelite's hotkeys worked better for me. I had to check a box in preferences to make it pull selected text in addition to ctrl-C'd text

Comment: glipper is lacking good search

Comment: I've found glipper very crashy, does it work fine for you?

Comment: glipper and parcelite are not in the ubuntu repository. clipit has been replaced by diodon

Answer (score 16):

**[Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon)** is now in the Ubuntu repositories.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install diodon -y
```

There's also a PPA with an updated version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install diodon unity-scope-diodon
```

Comment: This link is now dead :-(

Comment: Link is working again now.  +1 for Diodon.

Comment: Diodon is what is the closer to Ditto on Windows. It just lacks a shortcut that displays the recent copies, as Ditto do. But it's better than CopyQ and glipper IMO.

Comment: Diodon doesn't appear to work with 16.04 (at least it didn't for me).

Comment: @PaulBissex me too

Comment: Yeah, I went with [Clipit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkclipit/) in the end.

Answer (score 16):

**[CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/)** is a cross-platform clipboard manager written in Qt that comes with many advanced features.

[image: CopyQ clipboard manager]

**CopyQ features:**

- configurable history size, number of tray menu items, multiple clipboards etc.;
- editable and searchable clipboard history;
- encryption;
- synchronization;
- keyboard shortcuts for opening the clipboard history, show the tray menu and more;
- commands: you can define actions or commands when a text copied to the clipboard matches some criteria you set. This can be used for instance to open video player if text copied to the clipboard is an URL with multimedia content and so on;
- image support: when you copy a selection in GIMP, an image in Shutter (take a screenshot), etc., the image preview is displayed in the tray menu as well as in the clipboard history. This obviously doesn't work if you copy some image file (e.g.: in Nautilus) since that's treated like any other file;
- Customizable appearance;
- command line support: tabs, items, clipboard and configuration can be changed through command line interface;
  more.

[image: CopyQ clipboard history]

[image: CopyQ Commands / actions]

Comment: Way more features. Actively maintained +1

Answer (score 12):

**[ClipIt](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt)** is a Parcellite fork with Ubuntu menu integration.

```
sudo apt-get install clipit
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be complete, there's also the older "`xclipboard`".

Answer (score 2):

Under KDE (Kubuntu, etc) there's "Klipper".

Answer (score 2):

Try [anamnesis](http://anamnesis.sourceforge.net/).

I created it because there wan't an alternative for Ditto that works on Ubuntu, and especially because I needed to be able to search the clipboard history.

Note it is still under development and it needs more tests, but is working fine for me.

Comment: Clipit can search history

Answer (score 2):

[Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/) provides various ways to manage clipboard history.