# Is there a ClipX eqivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clipboard manager for Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/42991/clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu)

I'm looking for an application that allows me to store multiple items in the clipboard. On Windows I use ClipX for that. Do you know such a program for Linux (Ubuntu 9.10)?

---

**Answer**
Initially I used glipper. But somehow glipper breaks copying images and [the bug has been in there since 2007](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glipper/+bug/104432) so a quick fix seems unlikely. Therefore I use Klipper with Gnome now.

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/42991/clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, I saw that it was a duplicate only after posting the question. I guess it was not recommended before because I had neither "clipboard" nor "Ubuntu" in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper) is a clipboardmanager for the GNOME Panel. It maintains a history of text copied to the clipboard from which you can choose. You can see this as a GNOME counterpart to KDE's Klipper.

[image]

Comment: oh I am sorry !!! i didn't know that you already  got the answer

Answer (score 1):

There's also an older application called "`xclipboard`".