# What software can I use to give my computer multiple copy and paste shortcuts?

Tags: windows, linux, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I would like to have the ability to copy multiple items with different shortcuts, and have different past shortcuts, each linked to one of the copy shortcuts. For example, pressing `ctrl+v` would paste whatever I had copied with `ctrl+c`, while pressing `ctrl+shift+v` would copy whatever I had copied with `ctrl+shift+c`. Ideally, I would like it to use different combinations of the meta keys plus c/v. Does anyone know some free software that can provide this functionality? I use Windows and Fedora, and would like something for each of them, preferably something very lightweight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best copy and paste software for windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/126967/best-copy-and-paste-software-for-windows) and/or [Whats the best 'simple' clipboard manager available?](http://superuser.com/questions/13258/whats-the-best-simple-clipboard-manager-available) and/or [Clipboard manager for Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/42991/clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu) and/or [Recommend please multiple record clipboard manager](http://superuser.com/questions/106211/recommend-please-multiple-record-clipboard-manager)

Comment: None of the answers for those questions do what I want. They all seem to have pop-up paste menus. I don't need a large history of everything I've copied, I just want a few discrete clipboards, each with its own meta-combination.

Comment: I guess when a question has an accepted answer that does *not* answer my question, I consider it a different question. Edit: Hmph, now it looks like I'm talking to myself -.-

Comment: Yeah, but that's what the bounties are all about.

Comment: Hm. I had thought they were to provide extra incentive to answer a question that hadn't been answered yet. Edit: Hm, I see. Alright, I'll look into doing that if I don't get an answer here today.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+c` and `ctrl+shift+v` have special commands associated with them as it is in most software. You need a clipboard manager with hotkeys for different items stored in it.

Comment: @dnbrv Those were just examples, It doesn't have to be those specific combinations, just some combinations of meta-keys and c/v.

Answer (score 3):

[Tenclips](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/tenclips-copy-multiple-text-items-to-clipboard/)? It has 10 clipboards, and is hotkey driven, you select the different clip board with a Key combination and then paste it's contents with CTRL+V. It has other features as well, paste uppercase, paste lowercase, paste purified text (without formatting, which I find extremely useful). Hover over the tray icon and see what is in the current clipboard.

```
CTRL+1 and Then CTRL+V (pastes from the 1st clipboard)
CTRL+5 and Then CTRL+V (pastes from the 5th clipboard)
etc
```

Comment: Hm, closest answer I've seen so far, but still not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank thank thank you. I used this at an old company & couldn't remember the name!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.clipmagic.com/

You can assign multiple hot key for different thing you want to paste.

P.S. I have no affiliate with clipmagic, I just google it, and found that it answer your question.

Comment: The problem is, it assigns the hotkey to a specific bit of copied text. I'm looking for something where the paste hotkey is linked to a specific copy hotkey, so it will dynamically paste whatever I've copied with its linked hotkey, instead of a static paste of a certain object on the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

block the first items, copy using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then paste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

block the second item, copy using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then paste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, etc.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What program are you in, and what OS are you using?